# Multiplying matrices in HLSL

Tags: mathematics, directx, matrix, hlsl

I have code that calculates a position like this in HLSL:

```
output.ShadowPos = input.VertexPos;
output.ShadowPos = mul(output.ShadowPos, gWorld);
output.ShadowPos = mul(output.ShadowPos, lightArray.lightView);
output.ShadowPos = mul(output.ShadowPos, lightArray.lightProject);
output.ShadowPos = mul(output.ShadowPos, T);
```

This works fine, but I would like to multiply the matrix together first

```
matrix m = gWorld * lightArray.lightView * lightArray.lightProject * T;
output.ShadowPos = input.VertexPos;
output.ShadowPos = mul(output.ShadowPos, m);
```

Yet this doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your matrix multiplications like vector*matrix, like this:

```
matrix m = mul(gWorld,mul(lightArray.lightView,mul(lightArray.lightProject,T)));
```